# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError in python 3.6

Tags: python

I am getting this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'

This is a common error but I don't know what have don't wrong.

This is how my file hierarchy is:

```
backend
   |
   '----> __init__.py
   '----> server.py
tests
   |
   '----> __init__.py
   '----> linearregression.py
```

I am calling `predict` function in `linearregression.py` from `server.py`

This is my `linearregression.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model


def predict():

    .
    .
    .

    return_this  = []
    return_this.append(price_is)
    return_this.append(gradient_is)
    return_this.append(intercept_is)
    return_this.append(str(predicted_value))

    return return_this

if __name__ == '__main__':

    returned_values = predict()

    price_is = returned_values[0]
    gradient_is = returned_values[1]
    intercept_is = returned_values[2]
    predicted_value = returned_values[3]
```

and here is my `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from tests.linear_regression.linearregression import predict //importing predict function here

PORT = 8083


returned_values = predict()

price_is = returned_values[0]
gradient_is = returned_values[1]
intercept_is = returned_values[2]
predicted_value = returned_values[3]

def price():
    return price_is
def gradient():
    return gradient_is
def intercept():
    return intercept_is
def predicted_value():
    return predicted_value

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    name = price()
    gradient = gradient()
    intercept = intercept()
    predicted_value = predicted_value()()
    return "<h1>Price is: </h1><p>"+price+"</p><br><h1>Gradient is: </h1><p>"+gradient+"</p><br><h1>Intercept is: </h1><p>"+intercept+"</p><br><h1>Predicted value is: </h1><p>"+predicted_value+"</p>"

@app.route('/banuka')
def hi():
    return "Hi Jananath"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8083)
```

**I am using `python3.6`**

Can someone help me what have I done wrong?

Comment: from where are you executing the file?...I mean from which directory?\

Comment: I am calling predict function in `linearregression.py` from `server.py` which is in `backend` folder

Comment: I think you should try executing the code from the root directory where the backend and the tests folder both are present

Comment: That is not the solution to this problem right? This can be fixed but I don't know how.

Comment: I would suggest you to please have a try...few days back I was also facing a similar problem because I was directly executing the file from inside the folder and not from the root directory

Comment: Use `python ./backend/server.py` from a terminal in the parent path. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Still getting the same error when i try to execute the `server.py` from root directory. I am using `vscode` as the text editor

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the "scikit-learn" library correctly? 
If not them install it by using pip by running `pip install scikit-learn`. 
And this should resolve the error. 
If still throws an error, then try to reinstall it, by first uninstalling by running `pip uninstall scikit-learn` and then installing it again, by `pip install scikit-learn`.

Comment: i don't think this is something has to do with `scikit-learn` package. It doesn't recognize the `test` directory as a module.

Comment: Watch this out, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html